# Coldfusion Session Sharing, Proxy Server

Tags: session, coldfusion, proxy

I have a website running in coldfusion and has been reported that a user went to the site and logged into someone else s session. How is this possible, could the proxy server be the reason for this?

I am using: CF 8,0,1,195765  and do have some caching enabled in IIS

Application.cfc:

```
<cfset This.LoginStorage = "session" />
<cfset This.ClientManagement = "Yes" />
<cfset This.SessionManagement = "Yes" />
<cfset This.SessionTimeout = CreateTimeSpan(0, 0, 20, 0) />
<cfset This.SetClientCookies = "Yes" /> 
<cfset This.SetDomainCookies = "No" />
```

Comment: It could be any number of things. Caching, race condition, poor session management. You don't give us much to go on. Was the user intentionally trying to log into someone else's account? Or did it just happen? Are you sure they logged into the other user's session? Or did they simply receive pages intended for a different user?

Comment: I do have it heavily cached in the front end which i have removed now, No it wasnt intentional, the other user was part of the same organisation and they all use internet under a proxy server. The other user just went to the admin portal and was logged in without any credentials and the other persons details were shown.

Comment: FYI (since you're new here) to add details to your question you can actually edit your original question instead of pasting stuff like your App.cfc into a comment. Much cleaner that way.

Comment: I'm not sure how the details of your App.cfc help here.

Comment: It would be worth working out what proxy server they're using and which version. There's a lot of ways to get proxy servers wrong or misconfigured, so it could be that. You could also take a look over the IIS logs for the period and see if that gives you any clues. Does you app do any logging that could be of use? I have my apps write logs of login/out events (including session ID) and it's tremendously useful. You can configure IIS to log cookies, which helps correlate with your own logs if they contain session ID